# How to write this SQL Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

table1 has 3 columns:

Id    UserName    SubmittedDate
1     Joe         1/1/2006
2     Joe         1/1/2007
3     Nat         1/1/2008
4     Pat         1/1/2009

I want to return this:

Id    UserName
2     Joe
3     Nat
4     Pat

I just want just one record for Joe, the most recent one.

How do I write this query?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(ID), UserName
FROM table
GROUP BY UserName
```

Note this assumes that higher ID means later. It doesn't query directly on the Submitted Date field. For that, use Quassnoi's much more complex one :)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do perfectly.  I might need the more complicated ones later.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. If your ID column is an identity field that auto-increments, this should give you correct results, as long as the Submitted Date is set when the row is first inserted, and never changes later.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT  Id, UserName, SubmittedDate
FROM    (
        SELECT  Id, UserName, SubmittedDate,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY SubmittedDate DESC) rn
        FROM    table1
        ) q
WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: This is a little over my head, but I'll keep it in mind.  I might need it later. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

With only standard SQL:

```
SELECT Id, UserName
FROM table1
JOIN (
    SELECT UserName, MAX(SubmittedDate) AS MaxDate
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY UserName
    ) AS MaxDateTable ON table1.UserName = MaxDateTable.UserName
WHERE SubmittedDate = MaxDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Every example helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three potential solutions. Give them each a try and see which is better for your data and situation. Keep in mind that in situations where a username has two identical submitted_date values the results may not be what you're expecting.

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.username
FROM
    My_Table T1
INNER JOIN 
  (
   SELECT username, MAX(submitted_date) 
   FROM My_Table T2 GROUP BY username
  ) SQ 
    ON SQ.username = T1.username AND SQ.submitted_date = T1.submitted_date
```

.

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.username
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS 
    (
      SELECT * 
      FROM
         My_Table T2 
      WHERE
         T2.username = T1.username AND
         T2.submitted_date > T1.submitted_date
    )
```

.

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.username
FROM
    My_Table T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN My_Table T2 ON
    T2.username = T1.username AND
    T2.submitted_date > T1.submitted_date
WHERE
    T2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks. Always good to have choices.  I might need them.  I'll have to study a while.

Answer (score 0):

Ripping off @Quassnoi, but I like evangelizing the use of [CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx) in place of subqueries and most views.

```
WITH
query1 as(
    SELECT  Id, UserName, SubmittedDate,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName ORDER BY SubmittedDate DESC) rn
    FROM    table1
        )

SELECT  Id, UserName, SubmittedDate
FROM   query1
WHERE rn = 1
```